# Multiple sp_attach_db in one query

Tags: sql-server

The computer is dead, but I was able to copy out all `.MDF` and `.LDF` files from the hard drive.

I am trying to use sp_attach_db to attach the databases to the new server, using a "Query tool" to the SQL Server 2012 database.

This works if I do it one by one:

```
sp_attach_db 'uni_11_2010','c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.UNI\MSSQL\DATA\uni_11_2010.mdf', 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.UNI\MSSQL\DATA\uni_11_2010_log.LDF';
```

But the problem is that I have 500 different databases to attach. I have created a text file with all 500 `sp_attach_db` commands, one on each line - separated by `;`

But it only seems to work if I enter one command at the time.

It would be great if I could do all 500 at once.....

Thanks a lot for all help.

Comment: How are you executing this text file?

Answer (score 2):

If your "query tool" is using SQLCMD behind the scenes, you may need to put a batch terminator (read `GO`) between each statement - or at the end.

```
sp_attach_db 'dater', 'c:\data\dater.mdf', 'c:\data\dater.ldf';
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Brian. Did not seem to work though: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.Perhaps there is another way than to use the proprietary query tool? (Sorry, I am not familiar with MS SQL...)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with a BAT file and osql :

```
osql -S .\sql2012 -E -o dumpfile_dbattach.txt -Q  "sp_attach_db @dbname = 'uni_1', @filename1='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\DATA\uni_1.mdf',@filename2='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\DATA\uni_1_log.ldf'"
```

Topic can be closed now.